# A question on product measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two measure spaces with measures $μ$ and $ν$ and $E$ be a set in $X×Y$. If for a.e. $x$, the set $E(x)=\{ y| (x,y) \in E \}$ is a measurable set in $Y$, then is it true that the set $E$ is measurable in the space $X×Y$ under the completion of the product measure $μ×ν$? If it's true, how to prove this? If not, can anybody give me an exception to this? 
Thanks!

The inverse question is easy to answer: It can be proven that if $E$ is measurable in the product measure $μ×ν$, then for all $x$, $E(x)$ is measurable in $Y$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U$ be a non-measurable subset of $X$. Let $E = U \times Y$, then $$
  E(x) = \begin{cases}
    Y &\text{if $x \in U$} \\
    \emptyset &\text{if $x \notin U$,}
  \end{cases}
$$
i.e. $E(x)$ is $\nu$-measurable for all $x \in U$. Yet $E$ obviously isn't $\mu\times\nu$-measurable, because otherwise $F(y) = \{x \,|\, (x,y) \in E\} = U$ would be $\mu$-measurable which per definition it isn't.